# How Do I get Ride of the Missing Frequency in my RESULT USING SAS

Tags: sas

I am new to this and I already posted this question. But I think I did not explain it well.

I have a DATA inside SAS.
Some of the cells are empty[nothing in] and in the SAS output  window, they have a DOT in the cell.
WHen I run the Result, At the end of the table, It add MISSING FREQUENCY = 7 or whatever the number is...

How do I make SAS disregard the Missing Frequency and ONLY use the one that have result...
Please see my screen shot, code and my CSV:[OUTPUT DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE9bu.png)

[RESULT WITH the MISSING frequency at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjU4u.png)

```
/* Generated Code (IMPORT) */
/* Source File:2012_16_ChathamPed.csv */
/* Source Path: /home/cwacta0/my_courses/Week2/ACCIDENTS */
PROC IMPORT 
        DATAFILE='/home/cwacta0/my_courses/Week2/ACCIDENTS/2012_16_ChathamPed.csv' 
        OUT=imported REPLACE;
    GETNAMES=YES;
    GUESSINGROWS=32767;
RUN;

proc contents data=work.imported;
run;

libname mydata"/courses/d1406ae5ba27fe300" access=readonly;
run;

/* sorting data by location*/
PROC SORT ;
    by LocationOfimpact;
    LABEL Route="STREET NAME" Fatalities="FATALITIES" Injuries="INJURIES" 
        SeriousInjuries="SERIOUS INJURIES" LocationOfimpact="LOCATION OF IMPACT" 
        MannerOfCollision="MANNER OF COLLISION" 
        U1Factors="PRIMARY CAUSES OF ACCIDENT" 
        U1TrafficControl="TRAFFIC CONTROL SIGNS AT THE LOCATION" 
        U2Factors="SECONDARY CAUSES OF ACCIDENT" 
        U2TrafficControl="OTHER TRAFFIC CONTROL SIGNS AT THE LOCATION" 
        Light="TYPE OF LIGHTHING AT THE TIME OF THE ACCIDENT" 
        DriverAge1="AGE OF THE DRIVER" DriverAge2="AGE OF THE CYCLIST";

    /* Here I was unable to extract the  drivers age 25 or less and te drivers who disregarded stop sign. here is how I coded it;
    IF DriverAge1 LE 25;
    IF U1Factors="Failed to Yield" OR U1Factors= "Disregard Stop Sign";
    Run;

    Also, I want to remove the Missing DATA under the results. But in the data, those are just a blank cell. How do I tell SAS to disregard a blank cell and not add it to the result?
    Here is what I did and it does not work...

    if U1Factors="BLANK" Then U1Factors=".";
    Please help me figre this out...Tks

    IF U1Factors="." Then call missing(U1Factors)*/;

Data want;
    set imported;

    IF DriverAge1 LE 25 And U1Factors in ("Failed to Yield", "Wrong Side of Road", 
        "Inattentive");

    IF Light in ("DarkLighted", "DarkNot Lighted", "Dawn");
run;

proc freq ;
    tables /*Route Fatalities Injuries SeriousInjuries LocationOfimpact MannerOfCollision*/
    U1Factors /*U1TrafficControl U2Factors U2TrafficControl*/
    light DriverAge1 DriverAge2;
RUN;
```

Comment: You haven't indicated what you want as the results. I would recommend post that as well.

Comment: Why do you have IF statements between your PROC SORT and DATA steps?

Answer (score 0):

SAS will display missing numeric variables using a period.  So if there was nothing in column for DriverAge1 in the CSV file then that observation will have a missing value.  If your variable is character then SAS will also normally convert values of just a period in the input stream into blanks in the SAS variable.

Missing numeric values are considered less than any real number. So if you want use conditions like less than or equal to then missing values would be included if you do not exclude them by some other condition.

You can use a WHERE statement on procs to filter the data.  If you want to append to the WHERE condition in a separate statement you can use the `WHERE ALSO` syntax to add the extra conditions.

If you want the missing category to appear in the PROC FREQ output add the MISSPRINT option to the TABLES statement. Or add the MISSING option and it will appear and also be counted in statistics.

```
proc freq ;
  where . < DriverAge1 <= 25
    and U1Factors in ("Failed to Yield", "Wrong Side of Road","Inattentive")
  ;
  where also Light in ("DarkLighted", "DarkNot Lighted", "Dawn");
  tables U1Factors light DriverAge1 DriverAge2 / missing;
run;
```

The WHERE conditions will apply to the whole dataset.  So if you exclude missing DriverAge1 and missing U1Factors

```
proc freq ;
  where not missing(U1Factors) and not missing(DriverAge1);
  tables U1Factors DriverAge1 ;
run;
```

then only the observations that are not missing for both will be included.  So you might want to generate the statistics separately for each variable.

```
proc freq ;
  where not missing(U1Factors);
  tables U1Factors ;
run;
proc freq ;
  where not missing(DriverAge1);
  tables DriverAge1 ;
run;
```